# Is it possible to rewrite URL using <app-route>?

Tags: polymer, app-route

Consider I want to rewrite a URL from `/register` to `/tenant/register`, where:-

- `/register` does not have an actual view, as it only serve to make URL nicer.
- `/tenant/register` is the actual view, with a `<my-tenant-register>` view element.

Is it possible to rewrite URL using `<app-route>`? So that it can sort of have a virtual path and redirect to app-route accordingly with certain rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking PSK as an example, we need to add a `path-changed` listener in `<app-location>` as follow:-

```
<app-location id="location"
    route="{{route}}"
    url-space-regex="^[[rootPath]]"
    on-path-changed="rewritePath">
</app-location>
```

Then define the rules for the `rewritePath()` as follow:-

```
/**
 * Rewrite path before passing to <app-route>
 */
rewritePath() {
  let location = this.$.location;

  let path = location.path;
  if (path == '/register') {
    location.path = '/tenant/register';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the head of your question, add :

```
<app-location route="{{newRoute}}"></app-location>
```

top of your custom element and define a new route dynamically at your function as:

```
this.set('newRoute.path', "/tenant/register");// That you really want to go.
```

`this.set` method will direct your new target something like you have pressed `<a href='/tenant/register'>Tenant/Register </a>`

Comment: That's not what I am looking for as I already know how to change the route by setting `route.path`. I intend to rewrite the path before it get process by `<app-route>`. Your answer does give me a hint on the answer I am looking for, which I am going to share it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I thought the same; I saw, this answer is not exactly what you look for when I read one more your question, but I kept it instead of delete that may give another idea.:)